# Supersingular elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

what are the examples of elliptic curves defined over  $\mathbb{Q}$ with supersingular reduction at a prime $p$ and having a $p$-isogeny over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Have you tried taking $p$ to be small so that $X_0(p)$ has genus 0, and looking for rational points on $X_0(p)$ that lie in the supersingular locus?

Comment: Self p-isogeny or p-isogeny to possibly some other curve? I guess self won't work because it will be CM and p will have to split in the CM field to get the p-isogeny, but then the reduction at p will be ordinary. If it's isogenous to another curve, then David's suggestion is a good one.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In fact, this cannot happen: an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is supersingular if and only if its associated mod $p$ Galois representation is irreducible, but if it is irreducible as a representation of $\mathbb{F}_p[G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}]$ then it is certainly irreducible as a representation of $\mathbb{F}_p[G_{\mathbb{Q}}]$ and thus it has no $p$-isogenies.

This argument doesn't work over larger fields: if $K$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ it's no longer true that $E/K$ is supersingular if and only if $E[p]$ is irreducible as a $\mathbb{F}_p[G_{K}]$-module, cf. [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107175/does-the-p-torsion-of-an-elliptic-curve-with-good-reduction-over-a-local-field). In particular, one can have an elliptic curve $E / \mathbb{Q}$ with a $p$-isogeny and bad reduction at $p$, and a number field $F / \mathbb{Q}$ such that $E$ has good supersingular reduction at all primes of $F$ above $p$; my previous suggestion to look for points on $X_0(p)$ gives lots of examples of this.

Comment: for the same problem can we replace the p isogeny over Q with p isogeny over Q($ \mu_{p} $) and have examples ? ( where $ \mu_{p} $ is a primitive p-1 th root of unity.)

Comment: @Suman, a rough computation tells me that the ramification necessary for this is not $p-1$ but $p+1$. This is getting a bit technical, so if you’re strongly interested in this, just e-mail me directly (find my e-mail on my home page), and we can discuss.

Answer (score 18):

I felt that there couldn’t be such an isogeny, but when I saw @DavidLoeffler’s answer, I realized that I had an argument, too. The formal group of the elliptic curve would be of height two, defined over $\mathbb Z_p$, but such things don’t have $p$-isogenies: the quotient formal group is definable only over a suitably ramified extension.